# $|(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_k})- (\frac{1}{b_1}+\frac{1}{b_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{b_k})|<\frac{1}{3000}$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $X$ be a set of 16 distinct positive integers. Prove that there exists a positive integer $k \leq 8$ and there exist two $k$-element disjoint subsets ${{a_1}, \dots, {a_k}}$ and ${{b_1}, \dots, {b_k}}$ of $X$, such that
$$|(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_k})- (\frac{1}{b_1}+\frac{1}{b_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{b_k})|<\frac{1}{3000}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an application of the pigeonhole principle.  Given the conditions, the largest possible sum is:

$$\sum_{k=1}^8 \frac 1k = \frac {761}{280}.$$

All of the numbers are positive so the smallest possible sum is greater than $0$.  And there are $\binom{16}{8}=12,870$ ways to choose subsets of $8$ numbers from $16$ choices.  Doing the long division, we find $\frac{761}{280 \cdot 12870} \lt \frac{1}{3000}$, so two distinct subsets must have reciprocals that sum to a difference of less than $\frac {1}{3000}.$  Cull out common elements of the two subsets and you have your answer.

Comment: Thanks so much Robert Shore

Comment: @Yaya I'm glad I could help.  If you find an answer helpful, upvotes and acceptances are always appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom{16}{8} = 12870$ size 8 subsets of $X$. The maximum reciprocal sum of such a subset is $1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots +\frac{1}{8} = 761/280$. Consider intervals $I_i = [\frac{1}{3000} i, \frac{1}{3000}(i+1) )$, of which $\lceil \frac{761}{280} \cdot 3000 \rceil = 8154$ are needed to cover the interval $[0,761/280]$. By the pigeonhole principle, there are two distinct sets of size 8, $A$ and $B$ whose reciprocal sums lie in the same $I_i$. Thus the absolute value of the difference of the reciprocal sums for $A$ and $B$ is at most $\frac{1}{3000}$. Taking the sets $\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\} = A\setminus A\cap B$ and $\{b_1,\ldots,b_k\} = B\setminus A\cap B$ then have the desired property.

Comment: Thanks so much Vujazzman